# Upload to web on dropping file to a folder like dropbox

Tags: c#, .net

There are similar questions like this in stackoverflow but none of them fulfills my requirements.

I want that when user move a file to his folder in desktop, that file should be uploaded to a web server (i.e. a one way drobox feature).

Technically, I want a listener who can check when a file is dropped to a folder and trigger an uploading function.

p.s. Will prefer code or resources in .net.

Comment: You stated what you want, but what is your specific programming related question ?

Comment: I code for web. Not sure about the desktop apps. I'll prefer a .net way as I use asp.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think its what I need. But I haven't anything on desktop applciation. Can you some sample code or a resource ?

Comment: There is an example in the documentation; what else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor the folder. Then you upload the changed files with one of the methods available on your web server.